# Llvm_executionengine fails to execute pointer operations correctly

Tags: ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to generate code to box and unbox values in my untyped language. For evaluating a simple integer literal 3, I generate:

```
define i64 @0() {
entry:
  %value = alloca { i64, [10 x i8], <10 x i64> }
  %boxptr = getelementptr inbounds { i64, [10 x i8], <10 x i64> }* %value, i32 0, i32 0
  store i64 3, i64* %boxptr
  %boxptr1 = getelementptr inbounds { i64, [10 x i8], <10 x i64> }* %value, i32 0, i32 0
  %load = load i64* %boxptr1
  ret i64 %load
}
```

Seems right, and `lli` evaluates it to 3, but Llvm_executionengine evaluates the function to 216172782113783808 (junk value). The code from my `toplevel.ml` looks like:

```
open Llvm_executionengine

let the_execution_engine = ExecutionEngine.create_interpreter the_module

let print_and_jit se =
  let f = sexpr_matcher se in
  let result = ExecutionEngine.run_function f [||] the_execution_engine in
  print_string "Evaluated to ";
  print_int (GenericValue.as_int result);
```

What's wrong with my interpreter?

Comment: `lli` is old and unsupported. What kind of EE are you using- JIT or MCJIT? And what's your LLVM version? Host/target triples?

Comment: I was just using `lli` to check that my generated code is sane. I'm using JIT, not MCJIT. My LLVM version is 3.4.2, and my host/ target is core-avx-i/ x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0.

Comment: I found out that my ExecutionEngine.create is falling back to ExecutionEngine.create_interpreter. Forget the JIT; it's not working.

Comment: The interpreter is unsupported. Pretty much the only execution engine that's supported is MCJIT now. Try that.